# Excel sumifs comparing two columns value

Tags: excel, excel-formula, compare, sumifs

So im trying to sum a column only for a specific group when the Date column is greater than the Transferral Date. For example Sum all the payments that were done after the trasnfer date for the Company AGC. So far I have this

```
=+SUMIFS('669287_1393_MX_Exa_Payments_GRL'!C2:C926,'669287_1393_MX_Exa_Payments_GRL'!B2:B926,">"&'669287_1393_MX_Exa_Payments_GRL'!A2:A926)
```

The problem is that because its comparing all columns, the result will be for all rows intead of just one.
First Stack Overfloow so Im learning :(  [Excel file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JfcIE.png)

I already try to find the question online and try to use GPT but still unable to find the answer. Also tried a formula like this

```
=+SUM(C:C*(B:B>=A:A)*(D:D=H2))
```

but didnt work

Comment: So you want the answer just for one row? That would be an if statement.=if(b1>a1,a1,0). You could then sum all of theses answers.

Comment: Further to my answer below;  You're `SUM()` approach was heading down the right track, but (a) the SUM() function pre-Office 365 won't do the sum correctly, so you'd use SUPRODUCT().  (b) Don't you want `E:E` and not `D:D`?  (c) If you are using 2007 Excel or earlier, the use of a full column like `E:E` is not permitted as an array argument to a function.

Answer (score 0):

There's some pieces missing or misused here.

- Your function is creating a 925-row-long array of *answers* and that is not what you want.
- Also, you're going to have to row-lock your source ranges with dollar signs.
- The various ...IFS() functions, like `=SUMIFS()` aren't intended to actually allow complex comparisons.  This is where a more advanced approach using `SUMPRODUCT()` comes in.  It's far too big a topic to delve into too much detail here, but understanding the `SUMPRODUCT()` approach to more complex conditions is a really important advanced Excel skill worth mastering.  It's worth reading about and watching some videos to fully grasp.

In cell I2:

`=SUMPRODUCT( C$2:C$926 * ( B$2:B$926 > A$2:A$926) * ( E$2:E$926 = H2 ) )`

Then copy or fill that down to H3, H4, and H5...  or however many companies you want to sum for.  Remeber that the $ signs before the row numbers in A through E are important.

If the result table is going to be on a different sheet, say starting in A2 with the results in B2, that's when you'll need to fully qualify the sheet name like this, but only for the lookup data.  Notice the A2 is neither locked with a $ nor is it qualified with a sheet name:

`SUMPRODUCT( '669287_1393_MX_Exa_Payments_GRL'!C$2:C$926 * ( '669287_1393_MX_Exa_Payments_GRL'!B$2:B$926 > '669287_1393_MX_Exa_Payments_GRL'!A$2:A$926) * ( '669287_1393_MX_Exa_Payments_GRL'!E$2:E$926 = A2 ) )`

Then, copy/fill that formula down B2, B3, etc. for however many companies you are summing.

Comment: I didnt knew that there are diferent levels of comparison for the formulas. Thanks for the help. It worked nicely

Answer (score 0):

### Sum Conditionally

```
=LET(Amounts,(A2:A926<B2:B926)*C2:C926,Comps,E2:E926,LComps,H2:H5,
BYROW(LComps,LAMBDA(LComp,SUM(Amounts*(Comps=LComp)))))
```

[image]

Comment: I have never used this formula before but it worked greately. Thanks for the knowledge.